# beginner at react.js - rendering component from state which is updated later

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, urlfetch

I'm trying to test rendering a list component from an JSON object called with fetch, however I suspect the render is called before the JSON is returned as I get an undefined error. Note the debug alert() gets the value, but the render has already error on undefined. How do I handle this? Is there a way to call the render function after the data has been fetched? OR could how would I get the data to render with '?' and then update when the data arrives?  Note my if (!object) doesn;t work when called as an inline wrapper - why not - or more impoartanly how would I achive this? Sorry for the begginer questions - I suspect I meant to be using a data framework to bring data for react to display but I wanted to start learning with less frameworks and get the basics. Many thanks! - code is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
class ItemLister extends React.Component {
constructor(props ) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { items: [] };
}
componentDidMount() {
  let url = "http://localhost:8888";
  let iterator = fetch(url, {method: 'GET'});
  iterator
    .then(response => {
     //console.log('sss', response)
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(post => {
      //console.log(post)
      this.state.items = post;
      alert(this.state.items.users[3].firstname);
    });
} 
 output(object){
    if (!object){
        return '?';
    }else{
        return object;
    }
}
render() {        
    return(
        <div>
            <div>Items:</div>
            <div>{this.output(this.state.items.users[3].firstname)}</div>
        </div>  
    );
}
}              
export default ItemLister;
```

Comment: Yes, it's a basic thing with React or other such frameworks. You render a placeholder/loading/whatever when there's no data and when the state changes the component will be rendered again and you rendet the actual data. The reason why it doesn't work is because you try to access `this.state.items.users...` and it doesn't exist so it doesn't even get to the function.

Answer (score 1):

your render function could be something like this:

`render() {
    const username = (this.state.items === []) ? placeholder :       this.output(this.state.items.users[3].firstname;
    return(
        <div>
            <div>Items:</div>
            <div>{username}</div>
        </div>

    );
}`

basically, you render a placeholder component until your data arrives, since your data fetch is async and in componentDidMount, so your render will happen initially before you have data.

although you probably want to rethink how this component is constructed in general, why are you accessing specifically users[3]?

Comment: Many thanks Conan. I'm just doing this as a test at the moment. I really need to store the full JSON object in the state and then render a list using several fields. Will your code sample work to store all items, and then use .map to output many <div>{first_name} blah blah {favourite_food} </div>. I'll try your code now. Thanks again, and very grateful if you coudl show me how to extend to do a list of several items from the items JSON?

Comment: I've not been able to get this working yet. Can you explain how the placeholder works? do i need to define it? elsewhere. Is the output a key word? Sorry, I'm very new to this, and some of the new/JSX syntax ie ? and ===. Many thanks again

Comment: change this line to this:  
const placeholder = "waiting for items...";
const username = (this.state.items === []) ? placeholder :       this.output(this.state.items.users[3].firstname;

Comment: hey andrew, you can make placeholder a string, a component like <Placeholder>, etc

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will help you

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
class ItemLister extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { items: [], firstname: "" };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    let url = "http://localhost:8888";
    let iterator = fetch(url, { method: "GET" });
    iterator
      .then(response => {
        //console.log('sss', response)
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(post => {
        //console.log(post)
        this.setState({
          items: post,
          firstname: this.state.items.users[3].firstname
        });
        alert(this.state.items.users[3].firstname);
      });
  }
  output(object) {
    if (!object) {
      return "?";
    } else {
      return object;
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Items:</div>
        <div>{this.state.firstname}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default ItemLister;
```